# How to if few letters are part of the string entered?

Tags: python, python-idle

Can somebody pls help me on how to write the code to check if few given letters are part of the string entered. the output must be true if the letters are present or false.

For example: Return True if and only if the name is valid (that is, it contains no characters other than 'B' 'A' 'N') if the word entered is BANANA.

Pls help me with the code.

Comment: If the name must contain no characters other than 'B' 'A' 'N' and the word entered is "BANANA", why not just check if the word entered is "BANANA"? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: `set('BANANA') <= {'B','A','N'}`

Comment: @falsetru He wants to check for both conditions, which is redundant because one of the conditions covers the other. I know that checking if the word contains only {'B', 'A', 'N'} does not mean that it is "BANANA".

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use regular expression `[BAN]+$`:

```
>>> bool(re.match('[BAN]+$', "TEST"))
False
>>> bool(re.match('[BAN]+$', "BANANA"))
True
```

Another way is to use sets:

```
>>> set("TEST") == {'B', 'A', 'N'}
False
>>> set("BANANA") == {'B', 'A', 'N'}
True
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To check `if` something, you use a conditional clause (`if/elif/else`)
2. To check what letters are used in a string, you can use a `set`. For example, if the input is `BANANA`, you can do `set("BANANA")` to create a set of unique values (`{"B", "A", "N"}`)
3. To check if certain letters are in the set, you can use the `all()` function. `all(letter in the_set for letter in ['B', 'A', 'N']`. Or, you can just compare one set to another (eg `{'A', 'B', 'C'} == set('abbcacabacacba')`
4. Finally, if the above conditional is `True`, then `return True`

Now have a go at writing some code. If you're having trouble, feel free to create another question supplying *what you have tried* and what errors occur/what the problem is.